# How to find college wise rankings and global rankings using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have the following data frame:

```
Agent_Name college_name  score  college_local_ranking  global_ranking
Anna          Harvard      60               1             4
Mathew        oxford       99               1             1
Angel         IIT          65               3             6
```

I'm able to find the global ranking using the rank function.

```
df['global_ranking'] = df['score'].rank(ascending=False)
```

Please help me in finding local ranking based on the score of their college.
I tried this but I'm getting error.

```
df['college_local_ranking'] = df['score'].groupby(by = ['college_name']).rank()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command :
`df['college_local_ranking'] = df['score'].groupby(by = ['college_name']).rank()`

will fail because you are subsetting the dataframe with `df[score]`, and then applying groupby on `college_name` which won't be present in this subset.

**The correct command would be:**

```
df['college_local_ranking'] = df.groupby('college_name')['score'].rank()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what could work for you

```
df.college_local_ranking=df.groupby("college_name")["score"].rank(ascending=False)
```

Hope that helps

Comment: This is very much the same as Mayank's answer above. When I started answering his response was not there, so apologies for the same answer again.